# Need feedback on the code that I have written, currently getting an error CS50

Tags: c, cs50

This is related to the CS50 course and I am trying to count all of the letters in a string.

The error:

```
readability.c:19:19: error: comparison of distinct pointer types ('string' (aka 'char *') and 'int (*)(int)') [-Werror,-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types]
        if (input == isalpha){
            ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~
```

Please suggest the alternatives to solve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(void)
{
    int letters, words, sentences;
    letters = words = sentences = 0;

    string input = get_string("Text: ");
    printf("%s\n", input);

    for (string n = 0; n < input; n++){
        if (input == isalpha){
            letters++;
        }
        printf("%d", letters);
    }
}
```

Comment: `input == isalpha`: `isalpha` is a function. Why are you comparing a string with a function?

Comment: `string n = 0; n < input; n++`: Do you understand what a `string` is? Looks like you are half using `n` as a string and half using it as an `int`.

Comment: `string n = 0` is wrong, `n < input` is wrong. What you want is `int n = 0` and `n < strlen(input)`

Comment: And then you need to test `isalpha(input[n])`

Comment: You need to go back and reread your instructional material, because you totally misunderstandd these data types.

Comment: Aside: you might get confused by `printf("%d", letters);` will run the count output from each loop together, e.g. `1233456778910111112...` Add a space or a newline, like `printf("%d ", letters);`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because `isalpha` is a function returning an integer (0 if the character passed to it is non-alphabetical, non-zero otherwise).

You should cycle through the string character by character. You should also change your counter's type to `int` since you can't perform addition on strings (nor can you compare them to an integer, so you'll have to stop the loop at `strlen(input)`). Finally, if you leave the `printf` in the loop the number of letters is printed at every iteration, so you should consider placing it outside.

A working cycle would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
    if (isalpha(input[i])) {
        ++letters;
    }
}

printf("The total number of letters is %d.", letters);
```